# Why is fetch query always returning error segment?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api, django-rest-auth

I am using the following code from react-native mobile application to make a social authentication call to [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) local link. However I am always receiving an error. Please let me know what is the issue.

```
  fetch(
    "http://localhost:8000/dj-rest-auth/facebook/",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type':'application/json'
      },
      xsrfCookieName:"csrftoken",
      xsrfHeaderName:'X-CSRFToken',
      body:JSON.stringify({access_token : resolvedToken})
    }
  )
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }  
  )
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

**Error Details:**

```
Network request failed
at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

**Alternate Error Update:**
If I use axios for the API request instead of fetch i.e. await axios.post instead of fetch, then i am getting the following error:

```
Network Error
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:14 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:84:24 in handleError
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: *"However I am always receiving an error"* What is the error? We need more details to help you with your problem. Please update your question.

Comment: If i log the data then it says undefined.

Comment: how about `console.log(error)`?

Comment: if you are getting `console.log(data)` undefined that means the code is successfully going into 2nd then block. You can log `console.log(resp)` to check the status code and messges if any.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Are you related to Pradip Debanath from youtube? Have updated the error from console in the question.

Comment: @Jayesh no mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233045/discussion-between-jayesh-and-rajdeep-debnath).

Comment: it shows your resolvedToken variable is not set.

Comment: @Joseph but resolvedToken is getting printed in console....

Comment: What does your API response look like if you got the same endpoint directly, such as via Postman? What status code does it return, etc?

Comment: @MattU It gives the key back after successful login via Facebook.

Comment: What HTTP status code?

Comment: @MattU HTTP 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was being faced due to the usage of localhost address for django local server call here. The issue remains for localhost or 127.0.0.1 as well.

Also, next I tried using mobile hotspot with my laptop and then used the currently assigned IP address of my laptop's Wi-Fi, to run django server and place API call to it. This doesn't work if using mobile hotspot and same error is faced.

However upon using a LAN router and then using the assigned local Wi-Fi IP address of the laptop, the issue was resolved.

This has now created new issue though. The API call succeeds and i receive the token only upon the first API call or first run. Thereafter I receive the error of missing or invalid csrf token.

However since that is a new issue and is different from this question, I am currently closing this question. If I am unable to resolve the new issue, I may ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that it cannot find resolvedToken Variable. so I have added on top of the code, and it works well.

```js
var resolvedToken = "2222";
fetch(
    "http://localhost:8000/dj-rest-auth/facebook/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      xsrfCookieName: "csrftoken",
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRF-Token',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        access_token: resolvedToken
      })
    }
  )
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Tried that. Same error persists. Also the resolvedToken already have the token value and is getting printed in console.