# react native expo not working in my mobile i can do in same wifi

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, react-router

> `[Blockquote][1]`
> uncaught error java.net.sockettimeoutexception failed to connect 192.168.10.4(port 19000) from/ 192.168.10.3 (port 48682) after 10000ms)

can not run in mobile I can run in the same wifi
it can run web base please tell me what should I do

Answer (score 1):

Please be a little specific with code so that correct answer can be suggested.

Based on your question I am figuring out that you're stuck with react-native expo using mobile hotspot.

You'll need to connect the laptop first to the mobile hotspot and then run

> expo start

so that the correct IP address is taken. Thereafter scanning from mobile expo app will run fine.

However if you are asking further deeper question about integration with social auth then you may check [my question and answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751230/why-is-fetch-query-always-returning-error-segment)